# Booting with an NVIDIA GPU, but without nouveau

Tags: framebuffer, virtual-consoles

I am trying to boot a Linux system (Debian 11) with an NVIDIA GPU; I need to avoid loading the nouveau driver, which I can do if I include some options on the linux command line (in `grub.cfg`):

```
terminal_input console
terminal_output console
set gfxmode=text
set timeout=5

menuentry 'Debian 11' {
  linux /debian11/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-22-amd64 console=tty0 ip=dhcp root=/dev/nfs ro nfsroot=192.168.50.111:/image/debian11,vers=3,nolock panic=60 ipv6.disable=1 rootwait vga=normal nofb nomodeset video=vesafb:off
  initrd /debian11/boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-22-amd64
}
```

The reason for doing this is that I need to load NVIDIA's proprietary modules, and it works OK, as far as it goes. The unfortunate consequence of this is that I no longer have the VTYs available - not a huge problem, since this is for a server that is mostly accessed via ssh, but sometimes it is necessary to look at the text console, so I'd like to have it back - but without loading the nouveau module. This used to be perfectly easy in the past, but it seems the kernel insists on loading a framebuffer device instead of just printing text.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Why aren't you using simpledrm/simpledrmdrmfb? It works just fine with NVIDIA.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I was not aware there was such a thing :-) I'll check it out. Does it require rebuilding the kernel?

Comment: Dunno, aren't you running your distro kernel?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yes - but I do't seem to find that option in the config file. If it is in the kernel already, how to I invoke it from the grub menu?

Comment: I understand `nomodeset` but who or what added `vga=normal nofb video=vesafb:off`? Those don't look appropriate or warranted at all. Try without them.

Comment: well, I added them, just trying out suggestions I'd googled.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I removed the unnecessary option, leaving only `nomodeset`; it boots as before, but no consoles. I guess I'll have to rebuild the kernel, possible without the `nouveau` and other unused drivers.

Comment: I highly recommend posting your issue here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148